# How do I delete a Non - primary Gmail account from Gmail app 4.3.1?

Tags: gmail, google-account

This was easy to do before the upgrade,  now it doesn't do this.  It  doesn't make sense to have to do a factory reset!   It's less intuitive!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll need to remove the associated Google account on your device. Go to Android's SETTINGS > PERSONAL > ACCOUNTS & SYNC. Tap on the account you want to remove. Next, tap the overflow/menu icon and choose REMOVE ACCOUNT

http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663649